# How to bind a service from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-service-binding

I can't figure it out how to bind to a service from a fragment.

Can anyone give me an idea about how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getActivity().bindService(intentToBindToService)?